# How can a Pokémon not know how to use attacks of its own type?

Tags: pokemon

In "The Winner By a Nosepass", Brock says "There's a small problem and that would be Treecko doesn't know how to use any Grass attacks."

But Treecko is a pure Grass-type Pokemon. How is it possible that a Grass Pokemon can't use Grass attacks?

Comment: "*Treecko has small hooks on the bottom of its feet that enable it to scale vertical walls. This Pokémon attacks by slamming foes with its thick tail.*" - So, it tends to use a Tail Slam (a physical attack) rather than an exclusively grass-type attack like Chlorophyll or Leaf Guard.

Answer (score 3):

In the games, a Level 1 Treecko only knows Pound and Leer, which are both Normal-type moves. [In Generation III](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Treecko_(Pok%C3%A9mon)/Generation_III_learnset#By_leveling_up), which is when that episode came out, Treecko had to wait until Level 6 before it learned a Grass-type move (Absorb). The other two starters, Torchic and Mudkip, didn't learn moves of their type until Level 10 (Water Gun and Ember respectively).

There's often a disconnect between a Pokémon's moveset in the games and its moveset in the anime - in this case, one would expect Treecko to have reached Level 6 by the time Ash reached Roxanne's Gym - but I certainly don't think it's out of the realm of possibility that a Pokémon in the anime could be born without knowing any moves of its type. It's certainly not uncommon in the games.